# Flink using S3AFileSystem does not read subfolders from S3

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, apache-flink, flink-streaming

We are using Flink 1.2.0 with the suggested S3AFileSystem configuration. A simple streaming job works as expected when its source is a single folder within an S3 bucket.

The job runs without errors--but does **not** produce output--when its source is a folder which itself contains subfolders.

For clarity, below is a model of the S3 bucket. Running the job to point to `s3a://bucket/folder/2017/04/25/01/` properly reads all three objects and any subsequent objects that appear in the bucket. Pointing the job to `s3a://bucket/folder/2017/` (or any other intermediate folder) leads to a job that runs without producing anything.

In fits of desperation, we've tried the permutations that [in|ex]clude the trailing `/`.

```
.
`-- folder
    `-- 2017
        `-- 04
            |-- 25
            |   |-- 00
            |   |   |-- a.txt
            |   |   `-- b.txt
            |   `-- 01
            |       |-- c.txt
            |       |-- d.txt
            |       `-- e.txt
            `-- 26
```

Job code:

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {

  val parameters = ParameterTool.fromArgs(args)
  val bucket = parameters.get("bucket")
  val folder = parameters.get("folder")

  val path = s"s3a://$bucket/$folder"

  val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment

  val lines: DataStream[String] = env.readFile(
    inputFormat = new TextInputFormat(new Path(path)),
    filePath = path,
    watchType = FileProcessingMode.PROCESS_CONTINUOUSLY,
    interval = Time.seconds(10).toMilliseconds)

  lines.print()
  env.execute("Flink Streaming Scala API Skeleton")
}
```

core-site.xml is configured per the docs:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.s3a.impl</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>fs.s3a.buffer.dir</name>
    <value>/tmp</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

We have included all the jars for S3AFileSystem listed here: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/setup/aws.html#flink-for-hadoop-27

We are stumped. This seems like it should work; there are plenty of breadcrumbs on the internet that indicate that this *did* work. [e.g., http://apache-flink-user-mailing-list-archive.2336050.n4.nabble.com/Reading-files-from-an-S3-folder-td10281.html]

Help me, fellow squirrels... you're my only hope!

Comment: _possibly_ relevant item that I forgot to add... https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-13208 indicates changes to S3A's listFiles in version 2.8.0. Flink docs suggest using `hadoop-aws-2.7.2.jar`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Answering my own question... with help from [Steve Loughran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2261274/steve-loughran) above.

In Flink, when working with a [file-based data source to process continuously](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/dev/datastream_api.html#data-sources), `FileInputFormat` does *not* [enumerate nested files](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-core/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/api/common/io/FileInputFormat.java#L225) by default.

This is true whether the source is S3 or anything else.

You must set it like so:

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {

  val parameters = ParameterTool.fromArgs(args)
  val bucket = parameters.get("bucket")
  val folder = parameters.get("folder")

  val path = s"s3a://$bucket/$folder"

  val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment

  val textInputFormat = new TextInputFormat(new Path(path))

  //this is important!
  textInputFormat.setNestedFileEnumeration(true)

  val lines: DataStream[String] = env.readFile(
    inputFormat = textInputFormat,
    filePath = path,
    watchType = FileProcessingMode.PROCESS_CONTINUOUSLY,
    interval = Time.seconds(10).toMilliseconds)

  lines.print()
  env.execute("Flink Streaming Scala API Skeleton")
```

}

Answer (score 0):

What version of Hadoop is under this?

If this has stopped with Hadoop 2.8, is probably a regression, meaning probably my fault. First file a JIRA @ [issues.apache.org](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/Dashboard.jspa) under FLINK, then, if its new in 2.8.0 link it as broken-by HADOOP-13208

The code snippet here is a good example that could be used for a regression test, and it's time I did some for Flink.

That big `listFiles()` change moves the enum of files under a path from a recursive treewalk to a series of flat lists of all child entries under a path: it works fantastically for everything else (distcp, tests, hive, spark) and has been shipping in products since Dec '16; I'd be somewhat surprised if it is the cause, but not denying blame. Sorry

Comment: Originally, this was Flink 1.2.0 / Scala 2.11 / Hadoop 2.7.0, with the added hadoop-aws-2.7.2.jar (per Flink docs). It's one of the "factory" download options from the Flink website.


I have since tried varying the Hadoop version and/or hadoop-aws.jar version and building locally. I've gone up to 2.8.0 and down to 2.6.0 with no success.

I had hoped that going **up** to Hadoop 2.8.0 would solve it, but it appears that Flink 1.2.0 can't play nice with that version of Hadoop. Flink master is not building currently... I'll throw some more things at this tomorrow.

Comment: Well, if it's in Hadoop 2.7, then its not the new listing. Why not see if it works locally (file://))) or hdfs...if it works there and not on s3a, then something s3a is (not) doing is a likely cause

Comment: Of course! Check the obvious thing first. I'll answer my own question below. This had nothing to do with s3a and everything to do with a subtle Flink option. Thank you for your help and patience.

Answer (score 0):

As with flink 1.7.x version Flink provides two file systems to talk to Amazon S3, `flink-s3-fs-presto` and `flink-s3-fs-hadoop`. Both `flink-s3-fs-hadoop` and `flink-s3-fs-presto` register default FileSystem wrappers for URIs with the `s3://` scheme, `flink-s3-fs-hadoop` also registers for `s3a://` and `flink-s3-fs-presto` also registers for `s3p://`, so you can use this to use both at the same time.

Sample code :

```
//Reading Data from S3
// This will print all the contents in the bucket line wise
final Path directory = new Path("s3a://husnain28may2020/");
final FileSystem fs = directory.getFileSystem();

//using input format
org.apache.flink.api.java.io.TextInputFormat textInputFormatS3 = new org.apache.flink.api.java.io.TextInputFormat(directory);
DataSet<String> linesS3 = env.createInput(textInputFormatS3);
linesS3.print();
```